# Dynamic data from an input text Laravel 5.4

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to make the same action as the image below in one of my create forms:

[image: Image of the form]

I want to write the Id of the user and bring the name of it dynamically to put it in an input below, as is shown in the image.

How can I do that? I'm using laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0):

use ajax request like this

```
$("#id_of_input").keyup(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "http://example.com/api/name/" + $(this).val(), success: function(result){
        $("#user_name").html(result);
    }});
});
```

and add in web.php

```
Route::get('/api/name/{id}', function ($id) {
    $user = User::find($id);
    return $user ? $user->name : '';
});
```